# Google text-to-speech (Wavenet) Is there a list of date formats for each supported language?

Tags: google-text-to-speech

Wavenet correctly converts dates like 01/02/2019 into a spoken date. Different languages use different date formats and separators e.g. dd/mm/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy. Is there a list of date formats and separators for each supported Wavenet language?
Does Wavenet follow the country standard formats given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd strongly suspect that it uses something like the data from CLDR (probably by directly using a library like ICU (ICU4J or ICU4C) to handle its date parsing/formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The great thing about Google's text-to-speech (as well as others, like Amazon's Polly) service is, that besides plain text that you seem to be using, it accepts [SSML](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/) which stands for Speech Synthesis Markup Language. This allows you to provide XML tags to indicate how to pronounce certain parts of speech. Among them, dates:

```
<speak>
  <say-as interpret-as="date" format="yyyymmdd" detail="1">
    1960-09-10
  </say-as>
</speak>
```

(Example taken from https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/ssml#sayas)

As you surely know you can test this out directly in the browser here: https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/.